# Tabulator JS Validator Regex

Tags: jquery, tabulator

Tabulator JS with python flask.

```
columns:[
{title:"Number", field:"msisdn", align:"center", editable:true,  editor:"input", validator:["required","numeric","min:11","max:11","regex:\\77[0-9]+"]},
```

],

I want to validation cell when enabled cell editing mode.
Restricted numbers by format 77XXXXXXXXX
but this regex match not working,
I'm using analog match into jquery function, work great.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression looks wrong there, it should be `77[0-9]{9}`

so your column definition should read:

```
{title:"Number", field:"msisdn", align:"center", editable:true,  editor:"input", validator:["required","numeric","min:11","max:11","regex:77[0-9]{9}"]},
```

I hope that helps,

Cheers

Oli:)

Comment: Hi. Oli. Not working this match. Without problem let me enter the value: 1234567890. ((

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem. Adding custom formatter:

```
var numEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){
    var editor = document.createElement("input");
    editor.setAttribute("type", "text");
    var r = /^77[0-9]{9}$/
    onRendered(function(){
             editor.focus();
             editor.style.css = "100%";
    });
    function successFunc(){
        var n = editor.value.match(r);
                if (n !== null) {
                    success(editor.value);
                }
                else {
                   cancel();
                }
    }
    editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
    editor.addEventListener("blur", successFunc);
    return editor;
};
```

and in tabulator:

`{title:"", field:"msisdn", align:"center", editable:true, editor:numEditor},`

and have a fun ))

Thanx Oli, your Tabulator JS is fire!

Answer (score 0):

```
{title:"Number", field:"msisdn", align:"center", editable:true,  editor:"input", validator:["required","numeric","min:11","max:11","regex:77[0-9]{9}"]},
```

does not work as within Tabulator when handling the regex via `RegExp("string")` only, it needs to be `RegExp("string", "gi")` to ensure that all the regex is treated.